# Replacing a player in the GKTurnBasedMatch participants property

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

From Apple's [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKTurnBasedMatch), I understand that `GKTurnBasedMatch`'s `participants` property has a fixed size that is determined at the beginning of the match.  Furthermore, I understand the maximum allowed size of `participants` is 16 players.  Is there any way for a player to quit the match and be replaced by another player?  In other words, if 16 players join the match, and one quits, can his/her spot be re-filled?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to remove a `GKTurnBasedParticipant` from a `GKTurnBasedMatch`.  Instead, "participantQuit..." and "endMatch..." functions set the participant's `status` to `Done`.  Thus, the participant is not actually removed from the match, and their slot remains filled.

Answer (score 0):

As [@codeperson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670400/codeperson) said, actually there's no known options to replace participants in any state of match. *But I've just found counter statement in the old official docs.*

Find [in this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html) part "Setting the Match Outcome When a Participant Leaves a Match".

[image]